# Response.Redirect using query string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access, query-string, response.redirect

Okay so I've just written my own "add a book to the database" ASP.net page that looks like so:

> ```
> <div class="addbook"><br />If you feel that we&#39;ve forgotten a book
> that you love, please fill out this form 
> below to help us keep the site fresh and dynamic!
> <h3>Title:</h3><asp:TextBox ID="tb_booktitle" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
> <h3>Author:</h3><asp:TextBox ID="tb_bookauthor" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
> <h3>Publication Date:</h3><asp:TextBox ID="tb_bookpubyear" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>    <asp:CompareValidator
> ID="CompareValidatorTextBox1" runat="server"
> ControlToValidate="tb_bookpubyear"
> Type="Date"
> Operator="DataTypeCheck" 
> ErrorMessage="Date must be in the DD/MM/YYYY format)" ForeColor="Red"
> />
> <h3>Number of Pages:</h3><asp:TextBox ID="tb_bookpages" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" 
>     ControlToValidate="tb_bookpages" 
>     ErrorMessage="Please enter a number." ForeColor="Red" 
>     MaximumValue="9999999" MinimumValue="1" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RangeValidator>
>
>
> <h3>Publisher:</h3><asp:TextBox ID="tb_publisher" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
> <h3>Book Cover:</h3>
> <asp:FileUpload ID="fu_picture" runat="server" />
> <h3>Your Rating:</h3>
> <p>    
>     <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl_Stars" runat="server" 
>     RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="142px">
>     <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
>     <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
>     <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
>     <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
>     <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
> </asp:RadioButtonList>
> </p>
> <p>
>     <asp:Button ID="btn_submission" runat="server" Text="Upload Book!" />
> </p>
> ```

And the code behind:

> ```
> Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
>
> End Sub
>
> Protected Sub btn_submission_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btn_submission.Click
>     Dim myGUID = Guid.NewGuid()
>
>     Dim newFileName As String = myGUID.ToString() & ".jpg"
>     Dim fileLocationOnServerHardDisk = Request.MapPath("img/thumb") & "/" & newFileName
>     fu_picture.SaveAs(fileLocationOnServerHardDisk)
>     Dim oleDbConn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BookMeetConnString").ConnectionString)
>     Dim SqlString As String = "Insert into booklist(Title,Author,PublicationDate,Pages,Publisher,imgurl,AverageRating)
> Values (@f1,@f2,@f3,@f4,@f5,@f6,@f7)"
>     Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(SqlString, oleDbConn)
>     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
>     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f1", tb_booktitle.Text)
>     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f2", tb_bookauthor.Text)
>     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f3", tb_bookpubyear.Text)
>     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f4", tb_bookpages.Text)
>     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f5", tb_publisher.Text)
>     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f6", "img/thumb/" & newFileName)
>     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f7", rbl_Stars.SelectedValue)
>     oleDbConn.Open()
>     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
>     Response.Redirect("detail.aspx?ID={0}")
>
> End Sub
>
> Protected Sub rbl_Stars_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles rbl_Stars.SelectedIndexChanged
>
> End Sub 
> End Class
> ```

As you can see in the code behind above, once the connection to the database has been made, i want to redirect to the detail.aspx (which is a page showing a single book record from the database and associated content) using a query string to show the record that was just added . But I receive an error like so:

> Input string was not in a correct format. Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a
>   correct format.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
>   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options,
>   NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
>   +10722195    System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +145
>   System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
>   +46    System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, TypeCode typeCode, IFormatProvider provider) +297
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter.GetValue(Object value, String
>   defaultValue, TypeCode type, Boolean convertEmptyStringToNull, Boolean
>   ignoreNullableTypeChanges) +126
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter.GetValue(Object value, Boolean
>   ignoreNullableTypeChanges) +63
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter.get_ParameterValue() +40
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ParameterCollection.GetValues(HttpContext
>   context, Control control) +247
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.InitializeParameters(DbCommand
>   command, ParameterCollection parameters, IDictionary exclusionList)
>   +257    System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments) +589
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +21
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +138
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +30
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +4
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +105 
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls()
>   +75    System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +83    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +974

How would I go about achieving what I am trying to do?

Comment: For one thing, your Response.Redirect does not indicate what {0} refers to. You need a second parameter that gives that information. What would the ID be and where would it be coming from?

Comment: The ID is a field in the 'booklist' table within my database (connection string is called BookMeetConnString)

Comment: I have opted for something like this:         Response.Redirect("detail.aspx?ID=" & Request.QueryString("ID")). The redirect works but the query string value is blank in the URL (i.e. "http://localhost:65458/detail.aspx?ID=")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a stored procedure that has an ouput parameter of the id of your newly inserted book and then do the following

```
If outputparam.value isnot nothing then
    Response.Redirect(String.Format("detail.aspx?ID={0}",outputparam.value)
end if
```

Please look at this url for more info.

[Input and Output Parameters, and Return Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59x02y99%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: thank you, I implemented something similar to this in the end!